# Sort a Tableviews sections in Swift 4 by a date that is in that array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, date

I need to create sections based on the date from one array and add the components that match into the array in order to display it like so: e.g

Array = [Mary's Birthday, Date(Dec 25th)], [Tom's Birthday, Date(Dec 25th)], [Like's Birthday, Date(Dec 24th)], [Jane's Birthday, Date(Dec 24th)]

*Dec 24th - Section*

Jane's Birthday - Cell

*Dec 25th - Section*

Mary's Birthday - Cell

Junes Birthday- Cell

Comment: Some details around your data structures would help, but, broadly, you can override the TableView delegate and data source methods to create the number of sections and rows per section you want, as well as provide separate views for headers  (the dates) and cells (the names).  You could use higher-order functions like .map() and .filter() to quickly put the data into arrays for the headers and cells, and then it's just a matter of implementation.  I hope that points you in the right direction, but feel free to provide more details if you'd like a more specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would like more details to asnwer the question, but i'll try to point you in a direction.  I would use a Dictionary for this kind of datasource.  This would allow you to have something like:

```
let dataSource = ["Dec 24" : ["Mary's birthday", "Jane's Birthday", etc...], "Dec 25" : ["", "", ...]]
```

Then for number of sections return:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return dataSource.keys.count
}
```

You will then have a section for each 'key'.  For your number of rows you will need to pull out the array for the section and return `count`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let sectionArray = dataSource[dataSource.keys[section]]
    return sectionArray.count
}
```

That will split your tableView in the needed number of section and rows.